# Including the Simple HTML Dom script doesn't work, but copy and pasting it into my file does

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have a weird bug I'm trying to figure out and it's killing me.

I have a clean install of MAMP on mac, so using PHP 7.0.12

When I try to include the simple_html_dom.php script, it doesn't work.  But if I copy and paste the entire script into my php file, it works fine.

I tried using everything from include, require, require_once, etc, and it didn't work.  Then i thought my includes weren't working, so I created a test script, included it, and was able to print out variables from that script no problem.

This may not be related to the simple_html_dom.php script, but does anyone know what may be causing this?

And as far as errors, I can't get any errors to display.  I changed my php.ini file to include all errors, have tried including error_reporting(E_ALL); in the script, I never see errors.

Sorry if this is a newbie question, I have literally spent hours trying to figure this out, searching google, etc,  and posting a question here is honestly my last resort.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the log file?

Comment: The file you’re trying to include might contain a specific-file-sensitive magic PHP constant like `__FILE__`.

Comment: Dekel,  I'm a bit embarrassed to say I don't know where the log file is.  I tried a google search, but everything was so outdated.

Comment: Marat - I checked the script, it doesn't contain a __FILE__ in it.

Comment: OK, I think I found the culprit.  The included script has a namespace at the very beginning.  If I just delete that, it gets imported properly (or at least the functions work properly).  Still not sure why that is though, but at least I figured out what is causing the error.